# SQLRecoverableException: I/O Exception: Connection reset

Tags: java, oracle, ioexception, connection-reset

Yesterday evening I left the office with a running Java program written by me. It should insert a lot of records into our company database (Oracle) using a JDBC connection. This morning when I came back to work I saw this error (caught by a try-catch):

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O Exception: Connection reset
```

The program wrote almost all records before getting this problem, but what if it happens early (just minutes after I leave the office at evening)? I cannot understand what happened, I contacted my database admin and he said there was no particular issue on the database.

Any idea on what happened and what can I do do to avoid it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This simply means that something in the backend ( DBMS ) decided to stop working due to unavailability of resources etc.
It has nothing to do with your code or the number of inserts. 
You can read more about similar problems here:

- http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=941911
- http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3800354

This may not answer your question, but you will get an idea of why it might be happening. You could further discuss with your DBA and see if there is something specific in your case.

Comment: I would also recommend a disk space check on your database VM to give your DBA a probable cause to proceed. df -h

Comment: none of the links work now.

Comment: Also not saved by the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 35):

The error occurs on some RedHat distributions. The only thing you need to do is to run your application with parameter **java.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom**:

```
java -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom [your command]
```

Comment: Been racking my brain for 3 days trying to figure this out, and your solution finally fixed it. What an off the wall problem!!

Additionally, for a more in depth answer, check out https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/230141007-Java-Web-Applications-Slow-Startup-or-Failing

Comment: 3 days ? it has been 2 month of headbanging here, much thanks ! (I guess OpenStack entropy throughput is WAY lower than VMware's)

Comment: where  do we put this config java -Djava.security.egd=file ?

Comment: You dont need to put it on any config file.  You only need to run your application with the line suggested.

Comment: You may also add the following line in your  $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security configuration file:
securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
Or "systemwide", configure the rngd service with option "-r /dev/urandom" and activate it/run it at boot-time.

Answer (score 30):

I want to produce a complementary answer of [nacho-soriano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110395/sqlrecoverableexception-i-o-exception-connection-reset/39332575#39332575)'s solution ...

I recently search to solve a problem where a Java written application (a Talend© ELT job in fact) want to connect to an Oracle database (11g and over) then randomly fail. OS is both RedHat Enterprise and CentOS. Job run very quily in time (no more than half a minute) and occur very often (approximately one run each 5 minutes).

Some times, during night-time as work-time, during database intensive-work usage as lazy work usage, in just a word randomly, connection fail with this message:

```
Exception in component tOracleConnection_1
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception: Connection reset
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:101)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:173)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:229)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:458)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:411)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:490)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:202)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:465)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    and StackTrace follow ...
```

##Problem explanation:##

As detailed [here](http://www.usn-it.de/index.php/2009/02/20/oracle-11g-jdbc-driver-hangs-blocked-by-devrandom-entropy-pool-empty/)

Oracle connection needs some random numbers to assume a good level of security. Linux random number generator produce some numbers bases keyboard and mouse activity (among others) and place them in a stack. You will grant me, on a server, there is not a big amount of such activity. So it can occur that softwares use more random number than generator can produce.

When the pool is empty, reads from /dev/random will block until additional environmental noise is gathered. And Oracle connection fall in timeout (60 seconds by default).

##Solution 1 - Specific for one app solution##

The solution is to give add two parameters given to the JVM while starting:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
-Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
```

**Note:** the '/./' is important, do not drop it !

So the launch command line could be:

```
java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom -cp <classpath directives> appMainClass <app options and parameters>
```

One drawback of this solution is that numbers generated are *a little less secure* as randomness is impacted. If you don't work in a military or secret related industry this solution can be your.

##Solution 2 - General Java JVM solution##

As explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss31/configwlss/jvmrand.html)

Both directives given in solution 1 can be put in Java security setting file.

Take a look at `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`

Change the line

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/random
```

to

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
```

Change is effective immediately for new running applications.

As for solution #1, one drawback of this solution is that numbers generated are *a little less secure* as randomness is impacted. This time, it's a global JVM impact. As for solution #1, if you don't work in a military or secret related industry this solution can be your.

We ideally should use "file:/dev/./urandom" after Java 5 as previous path will again point to /dev/random.

Reported Bug : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6202721

##Solution 3 - Hardware solution##

**Disclamer:** I'm not linked to any of hardware vendor or product ...

If your need is to reach a high quality randomness level, you can replace your Linux random number generator software by a piece of hardware.

Some information are available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hardware_random_number_generators).

Regards

Thomas

Comment: I just think about it, the **solution #4** might be to extend timeout period to go over the 60 seconds limit directly on the database server configuration.<br>In sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora Oracle's listener configuration file you can consider `TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT` and `SQLNET.OUTBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` parameters.

Comment: Can you please explain why you say the '/./' in Solution 1 is important?

Comment: @mrod He explains it, although I missed it on first read. It's because Java can "replace" /dev/urandom with /dev/random, so the '/./' solution prevents that.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation. I was wondering, since the entropy pool is empty, what if we wait for some time, say 5 seconds before starting to write to the database again, would that help? For example we catch the exception `SQLRecoverableException` in a try/catch block, and execute 'Thread.sleep(5000)` before starting to write to the database again?

Comment: May be a solution, without any guarantee as we hope 5s will be enough
Can't try and test your proposal as it's impossible to implement in Talend job :-(

Answer (score 7):

**Solution** 
Change the setup for your application, so you this parameter[**-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom**] next to the java command:

java **-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom** [your command]

Ref :- https://community.oracle.com/thread/943911

Answer (score 5):

We experienced these errors intermittently after upgraded from 11g to 12c and our java was on 1.6.

The fix for us was to upgrade java and jdbc from 6 to 7

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/java1.7'

export CLASSPATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/jdbc/libojdbc7.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

Several days later, still intermittent connection resets.

We ended up removing all the java 7 above.  Java 6 was fine.  The problem was fixed by adding this to our user bash_profile.

Our groovy scripts that were experiencing the error were using /dev/random on our batch VM server.  Below forced java and groovy to use /dev/urandom.

export JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom "

Answer (score 2):

Your exception says it all "Connection reset". 
The connection between your java process and the db server was lost, which could have happened for almost any reason(like network issues). The [SQLRecoverableException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLRecoverableException.html) just means that its recoverable, but the root cause is connection reset.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation when reading from Oracle in a Spark job.  This connection reset error was caused by an incompatibility between the Oracle server and the JDBC driver used.  Worth checking it.

Answer (score 0):

add java security in your run command

`java -jar -Djava.security.egd="file:///dev/urandom" yourjarfilename.jar`