# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to start up my application on k8s using the image Linux 4.14.165-133.209.amzn2.x86_64 and using openjdk 11 with maven, but the application does not start because of the following error

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:874) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:133) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) [spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) [spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109) [spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) [spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) [spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.b2wdigital.occurrence.service.OccurrenceServiceApplication.main(OccurrenceServiceApplication.java:12) [classes!/:1.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [occurrence-service-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) [occurrence-service-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [occurrence-service-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [occurrence-service-1.0.jar:1.0]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:870) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:355) ~[?:?]
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:174) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:555) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:258) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:190) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:132) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:105) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:91) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.net.ano.CryptoNIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(Unknown Source) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:764) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:429) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.receive(T4C8TTIdty.java:736) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.doRPC(T4C8TTIdty.java:647) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1702) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:588) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar!/:19.3.0.0.0]
    ... 58 more
```

**What I've already tried:**

- telnet, it connected to the port without any trouble.
- Connect by Sqlplus, it worked well but it had to install libaio
- The the steps described on [SQLRecoverableException: I/O Exception: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110395/sqlrecoverableexception-i-o-exception-connection-reset)
- Start the application on my machine,it worked well

The database is on oracle cloud and the range of ips is already allowed.

**More infos:**

Ojdbc8 version: 19.3.0.0

Database version: Oracle Database 11g EE Extreme Perf Release 11. 2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: https://www.usn-it.de/2009/02/20/oracle-11g-jdbc-driver-hangs-blocked-by-devrandom-entropy-pool-empty/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775784/836215

Comment: I've alread tried it but it worked for a short period of time no idea why, nobody changed anything. Now it does not work

Comment: When your stack trace contains `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon` then it usually means that database cut off the TCP connection, because your app could not "encrypt" the password fast enough. It is not a network issue. Try upgrade to Java10, this version does not have that flaw anymore. Otherwise you have set java.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom(Java bug 6202721). When you use /dev/urandom JVM will intentionally ignore you. You can also play with parameter SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT on DB server side, if you can.

Comment: Actually i'm using java 11 Is this bug yet on this version or is there any similar bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found this Oracle guide for this error, after looking here.

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2524953_1.html

This states that the issue is caused by high shared pool waits in the database.

The database alert log might show in this case:

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [KGL-heap-size-exceeded], [0x4289C41C0], [0], [524288008], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] 
Parse CPU to Parse Elapsed %: 1.20
```

The number shown is not supposed to be low like this according to the article.
Their given solution is to increase the minimum shared_pool_size in the database, and for more information, to go to For more details, to see [Document:330239.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=2524953.1&id=330239.1)

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue:
Fixed it by adding the protocol

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcps://{HOST}:{PORT}/{SERVICE}`

You should be able to use the same connection string with SQLPlus

`sqlplus {USER}/{PASSWORD}@tcps://{HOST}:{PORT}/{SERVICE}`